# Criação de relatórios

Tags: c#, datetime

Boa Noite, deve ser coisa simples, mas estou quebrando a cabeça e não está indo.

Fiz um relatório do projeto da faculdade "Entrada Peças em Estoque" e está funcionando perfeitamente. Quando fiz os testes o `DateTime` com a hora ficava zerado, depois acertei a hora e está funcionando perfeitamente o meu Form.

No entanto, apenas datas que estão com a hora zerada (`00:00:00`) aparecem no relatório, mas quando tem um hora especificada (`18:35:06`) não mostra.

Seguem as imagens e o código, estou fazendo o projeto em camadas, mas não faço ideia de como fazer o relatório pegando da camada `DAO`, então fiz na camada `View`. Está errado fazer assim?

[image: imagem com hora zerada]

[image: Imagem com data e Hora]

[image: Imagem Banco SQL]

código

```
 private void btnGerar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet dsum = new DataSet();
        DataTable oTable = new DataTable();

        String strReportPath = "";
        try
        {
            strReportPath = @"Report1.rdlc";
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = strReportPath;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DENILSON-PC;Initial Catalog=dbSistEstoqueEmp;Integrated Security=True");
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbEntradaEstoque WHERE data_ent = @dataEnt";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("dataEnt", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(maskDataInicial.Text);

            SqlDataReader oDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            oTable.Load(oDataReader);
            ReportDataSource myReportDataSource = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", oTable);
            reportViewer1.Clear();
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources[0] = myReportDataSource;
            reportViewer1.RefreshReport();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

obrigado bruno deu certo .date no meu parâmetro.

como estou fazendo em 4 camadas é errado fazer os relatórios na camada View ?

obrigado

Comment: Pode editar sua pergunta e colocar a configuração da `DataTable` no form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema encontra-se aqui instrução:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbEntradaEstoque WHERE CONVERT(DATE, data_ent) = @dataEnt";
(...)
cmd.Parameters.Add("dataEnt", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(maskDataInicial.Text);
```

Pelo que dá a entender o formato da data na base de dados é `datetime(datetime2)`. A tua instrução converte uma data no formato `dd/mm/yyyy` para o formato `yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss[.fração de segundos]`, com a particularidade que a componente `hh:mm:ss[fração de segundos]` é sempre `00:00:00 000`

A tua instrução SQL para obter os resultados na base de dados é a seguinte:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbEntradaEstoque WHERE data_ent = @dataEnt";
```

Pelo que só vai devolver os registos que tenham na base de dados 00:00:00 000 na componente `hh:mm:ss[.fração de segundos]`,

Uma solução passa por alterar a tua instrução para

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbEntradaEstoque WHERE CONVERT(DATE, data_ent) = @dataEnt";
```

e

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("dataEnt", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(maskDataInicial.Text).Date;
```

(Ou simplesmente converter directamente a String maskDataInicial.Text para o formato Date (sem hh:mm:ss)